# Check for duplicates in 2 columns of repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table #mytable with 2 columns :

```
<table id="#mytable">
<tr><td class="name">John</td><td class="surname">Smith</td></tr>
<tr><td class="name">Paul</td><td class="surname">Jackson</td></tr>
<tr><td class="name">Mary</td><td class="surname">Jane</td></tr>
</table>
```

I also have a repeater subfield, with 2 subfields as well : "name" and "surname".
I want to add a class to "#mytable tr" if the name AND surname are contained in the repeater.

I know how to check if one value is contained in one column of the repeater, but I don't know how to check for both values.

Here is what I have for one value :

```
 jQuery.each($('#mytable tr .name'), function () {
        var line = $(this).closest("tr");
        var name = this.textContent;
        var namesrepeater = $('#myrepeater .namesrepeater select option:selected').map(function() {  return $(this).text();}).get().join(',');
 
    if (namesrepeater.includes(name)) {
      line.addClass("yes");
    }       
  });
```

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: Track is using booleans? Then you can see if name is true and surname is true, then add your li class

Comment: Can you show your HTML for your repeater? Are there 2 select boxes, one for name and one for surname?

Comment: Hi @Cjmarkham thank you for your reply. 
My repeater is a ACF repeater (wordpress), pretty complex (I just used "name" and "surname" as an example). There are indeed 2 select fields (select2 fields, if that matters).

Answer (score 0):

So I think I understood your question correctly. Basically, we get a list of names and surnames from the table.

Then, we add an event listener on `select` so when one changes, we run a callback function.

Within this function, we get the name and surname values of the selects, then see if they exist in the names and surnames lists, then we get the `tr` with that name and surname using a filter and add a class to it.

```js
const names = []
const surnames = []

// Build a list of names and surnames
$('#mytable tr').each(function () {
  const name = $(this).find('.name').text()
  const surname = $(this).find('.surname').text()

  names.push(name)
  surnames.push(surname)
})

// Add an event listener for when a select changes
$('select').on('change', (e) => {
  // remove all of the classes because none of them may be valid any more
  $('.red').removeClass('red')
  
  const name = $('#name').find('option:selected').val()
  const surname = $('#surname').find('option:selected').val()
  
  // If the name and surname appear in the list of names and surnames
  if (names.indexOf(name) > -1 && surnames.indexOf(surname) > -1) {
    // filter out all of the tr's so we only get the one with the name and surname inside
    const tr = $('tr').filter(function () {
       return $(this).find('.name').text() === name && $(this).find('.surname').text() === surname
    })
    
    // add the class
    tr.addClass('red')
  }
})
```

```css
tr.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tr><td class="name">John</td><td class="surname">Smith</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="name">Paul</td><td class="surname">Jackson</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="name">Mary</td><td class="surname">Jane</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="name">John</td><td class="surname">Paul</td></tr>
</table>

<select id="name">
  <option></option>
  <option value="John">John</option>
  <option value="Paul">Paul</option>
</select>

<select id="surname">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Smith">Smith</option>
  <option value="Paul">Paul</option>
</select>
```

One thing to note is that if you can, you should probably query data attributes rather than using the text value of the `td` within the `tr`.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, i haven't had time to test your suggestion yet, but I wanted to thank you in the meantime. Be sure that when i test it i'll get back to you and approve your answer if all good. THANK YOU !